# USB C charging on Dell Inspiron laptop: OnePlus 65W phone charger

Tags: usb, laptop, battery, power

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop with a USB C port. The normal charging is 65W adapter via the Dell power (charging port).  If I connect this to my OnePlus phone charger which is also 65W somehow it does not charge the laptop.

Is this expected behaviour? Are USB C laptop chargers made somehow different from USB C phone chargers?

Interestingly I tried connecting to a monitor via the same USB C port and charging worked over that connection (albeit slowly).

---

**For more context**: The laptop "brick" charger is unwieldy and I wanted to switch to one of the new compact GaN chargers. The additional advantage I was counting on was that I would only carry a single charger during travel that can now service my laptop, phone and Bluetooth headset.

Edit: the phone charger is the standard OnePlus 65 W warp charger.

Comment: Specifications on the phone charger would be appreciated

Comment: Could be the difference between [QC (Quick Charge)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Charge) and [PD (Power Delivery)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#USB_Power_Delivery).

Comment: OnePlus has a non standard standard for full speed quick charging. Vooc/warp charge. It's not standard PD tho newer phones can do PD too.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek WarpCharge? Not even QuickCharge? Wow! What a crappy idea.

Comment: I can charge/run some laptops using a OnePlus 85W quick charger, and not others. The idea is that there are different protocols for charging, and different brands and devices can use different ones and these may not be compatible. They should all support the basic USB power functions, but these stop far before the various high-power delivery protocols others have mentioned.

Comment: Are there chargers that support both the proprietory one plus VOOC Charging protocol but also PD for other devices?

Answer (score 5):

The OnePlus One 65W charger does not support PD (Power Delivery) charging, while the Dell charger does.

Your laptop most likely uses 20V to get charged, using PD charging.

You should have a look at your stock power brick, there should be 20V @ 3.25A. Your new charger should have that, too.

Comment: The OnePlus charger *does* support USB PD at 45W. Only the top-tier 65W is proprietary protocol.

Comment: @iBug That's a distinction without a difference. OnePlus charger is **not** actually 65W for stuff outside the OnePlus phone. It is a 45W charger with "overclocking" only for their phone and people should treat it as such.

Answer (score 2):

OnePlus uses a 'non standard' fast charging method - [WarpCharge (Aka VOOC - which is the oppo branded version of it)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppo#VOOC), which moves some of the circuitry to the charger and in some variations even relies on a non standard cable. Its kinda useless for anything other than charging one of their phones (which it does fast).

A *standards compliant* USB PD charger *would* fast charge your phone *and* be able to do the voltages and power levels needed to charge your laptop. The OnePlus charger is not one of these.

Comment: Thanks. But the standards compliant PD charger would be slower than the one plus charger when charging OnePlus phones?

Comment: Yup. With older phones you'd not even get PD speeds - with ones that support PD, Warp's still ludicrously fast.  Its just better at that *one thing*. At home I run native chargers for things. Outside I have a good multiport GAN charger to save space

Comment: Exactly my plan!